# Get a room resource's calendar events from application

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is it possibly to query a rooms calendar events when authenticated with client credientals as an application with MS Graph?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with one of the following application permissions:

- Calendars.ReadBasic
- Calendars.Read
- Calendars.ReadWrite

To read events, use room email address

```
GET /users/{room_email_address}/calendar/events
GET /users/{room_email_address}/calendar/calendarView?startDateTime=2024-01-01T19:00:00&endDateTime=2024-01-31T19:00:00
```

If you received some error then you will have set mailbox folder permission in Exchange Admin Center.